# I used to have tabs at the top for each open file editor - now it only shows the currently open tab

Tags: tabs, visual-studio-code

[As you can see in the screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuTRo.png)
 I have 4 editors open (shown on the left side) but only the currently selected editor appears at the tab bar on the top. I used to have all 4 tabs open side by side at the top and could click on them like Internet browser tabs. I haven't found anything that tells me why this happened and how I can fix it. How can I return it to having side-by-side tabs for each editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you disable this setting?  Sounds like you didn't which is strange.

> Workbench > Editor: Show Tabs

Enable it to get all the tabs showing if it isn't already enabled.